# Connect to many databases in different servers

Tags: java, database, database-connection, datasource, multi-database-connections

Maybe somebody else asked this question before, but I've not found it yet.

My problem it's simple, I want to validate connection with lot of databases. I created a process in Java (I'm using Spring) that create datasources connection with some datas that obtained from a query. I just want to know if there's a better approach or a faster way to do it. My process take lot of time to validate the whole connections (near of 5K).

This is how my code looks like

```
public void validateConnections() throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    BasicDataSource dataSource;

    List<Element> elements = dataToCreateDatasourcesRepository.getAllDatas();

    for(Element element : elements) {
        dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Constants.DRIVER_CLASS_NAME_PROP);
        dataSource.setUrl(getConnectionUrl(element.getElementNbr(), element.getCode()));
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(EncryptionAlgorithm.decryptFromHex(password));
        try {
          Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
          if(rs == null || !rs.next()) {
            LOG
                .info(
                    "Connection for element [" + element.getElementNbr() + "]." + element.getCode() + " UNSUCCESSFULY ");
          }
          else {
            LOG.info("Connection for element [" + element.getElementNbr() + "]." + element.getCode() + " SUCCESSFULY ");
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
          LOG.info("Connection for element [" + element.getElementNbr() + "]." + element.getCode() + " UNSUCCESSFULY ");
          LOG.error(e);
        }
      }
  }

  public String getConnectionUrl(String elementNbr, String code) {
    return String
        .format(
            dbUrl,
            PREFIX.concat(elementNbr.toString()),
            code.concat(Constants.HOSTNAME),
            PREFIX.concat(elementNbr.toString()),
            code.toLowerCase());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establishing a connection is an [expensive operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303678/database-connection-expensive-to-create), which takes a lot of time on the server side. You're running a single loop which most likely stays idle waiting for the next connection. You may try using a [thread pool executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) to send many connections in parallel.

As a side note, you may also want to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements to automatically close result sets, statements and connections.